# With all last update on laravel passport, do I need to care about openid connect?if yes,why?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, laravel-passport, laravel-6

As I know `oauth2` is for `authorization` and if we want to use it to `authentication`, we have to use from `openid connect`. But in `Laravel` there is `Passport` pakage and it is built on top of the League `OAuth2 server`. When I look at it's document on `Github` ,the following `RFCs` are implemented:

```
RFC6749 "OAuth 2.0"  RFC6750 " The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework:    Bearer Token Usage"  RFC7519 "JSON Web Token (JWT)"  RFC7636 "Proof    Key    for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients"
```

anybody knows that do I need to do something else for `authentication` with `Passport`? or `Passport` has all thing that we need!

Answer (score 1):

Passport (and by extension OAuth2) can provide both authentication AND authorisation out of the box.

However, primarily OAuth2 alone is for *authentication* - is the user who they say they are (authentic) - with authorisation support (what privileges does this user have - authorised) being quite high-level (i.e. via scopes).

If you have fine-grained requirements for authorisation, you'll need an extra layer of permissions and role management and a way to associate the appropriate role with the identified user.

That's where OpenID Connect comes in: it provides a standardised framework for how to get user information out of the identity server so that you can apply the necessary logic to determine what they can and cannot do... but you don't *need* OpenID Connect to achieve this, it is just a standardised approach meant to provide a potential starting point.

Comment: OAuth2 is primarily alone for *authorization* and OpenID Connect adds a layer on top of this framework for *Authentication*. According to this, well explained, video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0

Comment: Great video, Nate is not wrong. But to be clear, OAuth in general is designed to facilitate 'delegated authorisation' which is about the user authorising one app to access their data on another. However, the protocol itself actually only handles the _authentication_ of the user and the _delegation_ of their authorisation to the 'client' app accessing their data. _Authorisation_ in the context of Hamid's question (my assumption of what he's asking) is really about roles and privileges within his own app: "is the _user_ authorised to perform x action in the app". Hence my distinction.

Comment: Ah ok, makes sense! Thank you for the elaboration.